# npgsql 3.0.2 entity framework 6 visual studio 2015 database first

Tags: c#, entity-framework, postgresql, visual-studio-2015, npgsql

I'm trying to use npgsql 3.0.2 with Entity Framework 6 database first on Visual Studio 2015.
I install from nuget Npgsql 3.0.2 and EntityFramework6.Npgsql 3.0.2.
When I try to run the wizard there no postgres Data source/Data Provider.

How do I setup it to be abel to run the wizard to generate my model.

Thanks.

Comment: did you work out how to install npgsql? im having the same problem - is it installed if we simply install the nuget package?